# How to handle several listeners in a dom element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-listener

I have a dom element (< canvas >) to interact with the user.The interaction with the user depends on the selected option. Since there are several options, I added several listeners in the DOM element, in several parts of the code.

Which is the best way to control different interactions? For instance, I've added two listeners for 'mousedown' event, one of them is to select an image and the other to create a new one. When the option to select images is enabled, then the corresponding listener should be executed, whereas the other listener should be blocked.

Now, I could handle this with a boolean, however, I have more than two options to interact with the dom element.

The dom element is in a factory to make it available in different controllers where the listeners are added:

```
    angular.module("app", [])
           .factory("myFactory", function(){
               var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
               return {canvas: canvas};
           })
           .controller("controller1", function(myFactory){
               myFactory.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){});
           })
           .controller("controller2", function(myFactory){
               myFactory.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){});
           })
           .controller("controller3", function(myFactory){
               myFactory.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){});
           })
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: expand factory to manage listeners and state conditions, then controllers only need to interact with the states. A directive to create the element would also help

Comment: charlietfl, thanks for your answer. I'll try it.